# the_permalink in loop gives the same results

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to show an archive list post by post. I created plugin with this code:

```
function posts_by_year() {
  // array to use for results
  $years = array();

  // get posts from WP
  $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
  ));

  // loop through posts, populating $years arrays
  foreach($posts as $post) {
    $years[date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date))][] = $post;
  }

  // reverse sort by year
  krsort($years);

  return $years;
}
?>

<?php function wyswietl_archiwum (){ ob_start(); ?>

<?php foreach(posts_by_year() as $year => $posts) : ?>
  <h2><?php echo $year; ?></h2>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
} ?>

<?php add_shortcode( 'archiwum', 'wyswietl_archiwum' );
```

When I put shortcode `[archiwum]` on any page, I get the list but every one item displays current page title and links to itself.

screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Any idea how to make it proper?

Answer (score 0):

`the_permalink()` and `the_title()` (and similar functions) use the global `$post` variable to determine which post to display. Because your `foreach` loop is in a function, in addition to calling `setup_postdata($post)` you also need to update the global `$post` variable.

The [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) details this:

> setup_postdata() does not assign the global $post variable so it's important that you do this yourself. Failure to do so will cause problems with any hooks that use any of the above globals in conjunction with the $post global, as they will refer to separate entities.

The simplest way to do this would be to add `global $post;` at the top of the `wyswietl_archiwum` function. Alternatively you could do `$GLOBALS["post"] = $post;` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: That's exactly how `the_date` is [documented](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) to work. The documentation also describes how to get the behaviour you want in the "Special Note".

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer for my second question. I fooled myself not to check at documentation. I used the_time('d.m') instead.